# PySpark: RegisterTempTable Lose Headers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've read in data using SQLContext and looking to run SQL queries on it.  I received the error.  Here is my code:

```
%pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
data = sqlCtx.read.csv("s3://recs-emr-sandbox/mtcars.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
data.registerTempTable("data")
spark.sql("SELECT * from data").show()
```

I get a result, but my headers are gone, therefore is basically useless because I can't properly write a WHERE clause.

Where am I going wrong here?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to register table first:

```
data = sqlCtx.read.csv(...)
df.registerTempTable("data")
sqlContext.sql(...)
```

Comment: I tried that exact command: df.registerTempTable("data") and then my sqlContext.sql("select * form data").show() and go the same error.  Am I missing an import?

Comment: @Bachzen you can use the same header name as of data original schema.